# Wireframing, mockup and interaction flow tools for SharePoint sites

Tags: development, architecture, design

I've been using Visio to mockup to design mockups and wireframes for sites, but I'm looking for other tools to help with the design process. I've been playing around with MS Expression Blend and SketchFlow, but I haven't found reusable components (i.e. libraries) pre-built for SharePoint.

Has anyone developed them, or found them somewhere?

Any other recommendations on UI/UX tools? Tools that can be shared with a team and saved on-premises are preferred. Intranet Factory? Balsamiq, Axure?

Answer (score 2):

[Balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/) has a good set of tools and is one of the favorites for some SharePoint designs. [Clever Workarounds](http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2009/04/08/review-balsamiq-mockup-tool-for-sharepoint/) has a nice review of the tools specifically for using them with SharePoint. There are two pre-built templates that I know of you can use with Balsamiq and SharePoint. [This one is for 2007](http://mockupstogo.net/prebuilt-sharepoint-elements) sites and [this one is for 2010](http://tuney.blogspot.com/2011/03/sharepoint2010-balsamiq-wireframes.html).

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 for Balsamiq Mockups. Here are some templates for the SharePoint  ribbon http://mockupstogo.net/sharepoint-2010-content-editing-ribbons